# JQGrid setGroupHeaders not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQgrid SetGroupHeader function and it is working fine in ie9, but when running the same code in ie8, it is giving the error "Unable to get value of the property 'startColumnName': object is null or undefined". I tried to debug the code and in JQgrid.js I noticed that columnHeaders array length is 2 even though I have defined only one record in the  groupHeaders array. Here is the group header definition:

```
$("#tblList").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
      {
          'startColumnName': 'Jan', numberOfColumns: 12, titleText: 'year 2014' },
    ]
});
```

Comment: Is this jquery v1 or v2? Check the docs for browser compatibilities.

Comment: I figured it out. It was due to a comma after the curly braces in the groupHeaders. For some reason IE9 did not give the error and IE8 assumed that there are two records in the groupheader array. Thanks

Comment: Ajay can you answer your own question and mark it as the answer so if this is found in the future the site visitor knows the answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was due to a comma after the curly braces in the groupHeaders. For some reason IE9 did not give the error and IE8 assumed that there are two records in the groupheader array. Thanks